# Android Custom Action Bar - want to get rid of top and bottom white space

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to create custom action bar in android. I want to get rid of the white space at the top and bottom. Can someone tell me how to do that?

the image is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3wY8EN07_OraVVJMEZyNUxIZ0U/view?pli=1)

Below is my style code.

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ProfileSetUpActionBar</item>
    </style>
    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="ProfileSetUpActionBar"
        parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
        <!--<item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>-->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Layout xml for action bar is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0080ff">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/back_arrow"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Sample" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Join"
        android:background="#0080ff"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity code. My activity is extending from AppCompactActivity.

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View profileSetUpView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_setup_actionbar, null);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        ActionBar.LayoutParams layout = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        actionBar.setCustomView(profileSetUpView,layout);
        actionBar.show();
```

EDIT1: My next challenge with the above question is, the text of Join button in my custom layout is displayed as JOIN. I want that to be Join and not JOIN. Can someone help me out with this.

I modified my styles like below. But nothing worked.

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ProfileSetUpActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyMenuTextAppearance</item>
    </style>
    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="ProfileSetUpActionBar"
        parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyMenuTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I fixed my second challenge by adding below to my styles

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ProfileSetUpActionBar</item>
<item name="android:textAppearanceButton">@style/CustomTheme.ButtonTextAppearance</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomTheme.ButtonTextAppearance" parent="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
<item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

**EDIT - 2** : My third challenge is the join button at the last has a thin divider like in this [link](http://www.codercowboy.com/2013/07/05/styling-the-contextual-action-bar-actionmode-divider-or-splitter-for-android/) next to that tick mark. I tried adding the below code to my styles in Apptheme but could not get rid of it.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ProfileSetUpActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearanceButton">@style/CustomTheme.ButtonTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@null</item>
        <item name="actionBarDivider">@null</item>
        <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
        <item name="android:dividerVertical">@null</item>
        <item name="android:dividerPadding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
    </style>
```

Can someone help me out fixing this up?

Comment: Instead of action bar why don't you use toolbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom view is inserted with some padding. 
Work around: You can set the color of your view same as that of Action bar so that space will not be visible. Or set the color to the action bar

Comment: Thank you works like a charm. Added actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0080ff"))); in onCreate()